# Rsyslog and ACL

Tags: linux, logs, acl, rsyslog

I'm redirecting log to `/var/log` with `rsyslog`, in order to let apache read the files, including new created files and directories i used `ACL`, in parent folder i did this :

```
setfacl -d -m u:httpd24:rx ../parent_folder
setfacl  -m u:httpd24:rx ../parent_folder
```

and i got this :

```
getfacl ../parent_folder

# file: httpd/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:httpd24:r-x                #effective:---
group::r-x                      #effective:---
mask::---
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:httpd24:r-x
default:group::r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---
```

And i have to change permissions with `chmod` to authorize `apache` in this directory, any ideas how to automatically give permissions to `apache` only with `ACL` (without changing owner )